# Combining two mysql results

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two multi-join queries. 
1 for products that come from the 'session' table, another for products that come from the 'package' table. Both queries have to join with my order and order_items tables.

A single order should look like this in our list of orders web page:

```
|order id  |  products|
|123       |  A2,PKG1 |
```

Each individual query group concats the products, but how can I group concat products from two different join queries?

My initial thought was a join table, but my co-worker said just use objects.

I really do not want to write code/construct objects since the products are just for display.

Can anyone make a suggestion that's quick an easy? Anything other than a join table or using objects.

**Here are my 2 queries:**

**sessions:**
select ats_store.order.payment_type,production_www.paypal_transactions.createdOn as order_date,production_www.paypal_transactions.FIRSTNAME as firstname,
production_www.paypal_transactions.LASTNAME as lastname,ats_store.order.id as order_id,ats_store.order.customerid,ats_store.order.shipping_address_id,ats_store.order.status,ats_store.order_items.product_id,ats_store.shipping_address.country as country,ats_store.shipping_address.street_1 as street1,ats_store.shipping_address.street_2 as street2,ats_store.shipping_address.street_3 as street3,ats_store.shipping_address.city as city,ats_store.shipping_address.state_and_province as state,ats_store.shipping_address.zip_code as zip,GROUP_CONCAT(production_cache_salesforce_repl.ats_conference_session__c.Name order by production_cache_salesforce_repl.ats_conference_session__c.Sort_Code__c) 
as products,production_cache_salesforce_repl.ats_conference_session__c.Sort_Code__c
from ats_store.order 
LEFT JOIN ats_store.shipping_address ON ats_store.shipping_address.id = ats_store.order.shipping_address_id 
INNER JOIN ats_store.order_items ON ats_store.order_items.order_id = ats_store.order.id
INNER JOIN production_cache_salesforce_repl.ats_store_price__c price ON price.Id = ats_store.order_items.product_id
JOIN production_cache_salesforce_repl.ats_conference_session__c ON production_cache_salesforce_repl.ats_conference_session__c.Id = price.ATS_Conference_Session__c
LEFT JOIN production_www.paypal_transactions ON production_www.paypal_transactions.id = ats_store.order.paypal_transaction_id
where ats_store.order.shipping_address_id != -1 and production_www.paypal_transactions.COMMENT1 = 'ATS Web Store' and production_www.paypal_transactions.RESPMSG = 'Approved'
group by ats_store.order.id order by order_date

**packages:**
select ats_store.order.payment_type,production_www.paypal_transactions.createdOn as order_date,production_www.paypal_transactions.FIRSTNAME as firstname,
production_www.paypal_transactions.LASTNAME as lastname,ats_store.order.id as order_id,ats_store.order.customerid,ats_store.order.shipping_address_id,ats_store.order.status,ats_store.order_items.product_id,ats_store.shipping_address.country as country,ats_store.shipping_address.street_1 as street1,
ats_store.shipping_address.street_2 as street2,ats_store.shipping_address.street_3 as street3,ats_store.shipping_address.city as city,
ats_store.shipping_address.state_and_province as state,ats_store.shipping_address.zip_code as zip,
GROUP_CONCAT(production_cache_salesforce_repl.ats_store_package__c.Package_Code__c order by production_cache_salesforce_repl.ats_store_package__c.Package_Code__c) 
as products
from ats_store.order
LEFT JOIN ats_store.shipping_address ON ats_store.shipping_address.id = ats_store.order.shipping_address_id
INNER JOIN ats_store.order_items ON ats_store.order_items.order_id = ats_store.order.id
INNER JOIN production_cache_salesforce_repl.ats_store_price__c price ON price.Id = ats_store.order_items.product_id
JOIN production_cache_salesforce_repl.ats_store_package__c ON production_cache_salesforce_repl.ats_store_package__c.Id = price.ATS_Store_Package__c
LEFT JOIN production_www.paypal_transactions ON production_www.paypal_transactions.id = ats_store.order.paypal_transaction_id
where ats_store.order.shipping_address_id != -1 and production_www.paypal_transactions.COMMENT1 = 'ATS Web Store' and production_www.paypal_transactions.RESPMSG = 'Approved'
group by ats_store.order.id order by order_date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify, do the folowing:

1) Create a view for each query that you want to join

2) Once you create the views:

```
SELECT ProductID, SUM(Amout) FROM 
(SELECT * FROM vw_View1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM vw_View2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM vw_View3) GROUP BY ProductID
```

Just make sure all the views have the same number of fields and names.

Does this fits your needs?

Comment: I would like to post both my queries, but the comments box states 'too many characters'. can I attach a file to this?

Comment: ericpap, this is great. Now that I think  of it, my co-worker did mention this. 

I get this for my order items: A1,A2,PKG1.
Exactly what I want!

I created two views, here is how I use them:

select *, group_concat(sv.products, ',',pv.products) from sessions_view sv
JOIN packages_view pv ON sv.order_id = pv.order_id

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT order_id, products FROM session

UNION

SELECT order_id, products FROM package
```

Comment: If only my query were that short! Not used to using UNION. I tried and got 'Incorrect Usage of UNION and ORDER BY'